# Font Pixeled - see attached prints

Tags: html, css, fonts

Hello guys I have a problem with my fonts, I don`t know why are pixeled as you can see in the attach. Cheers!
[image]

And you have there also a print screen of the print screen zoomed :D <3
[image]

Comment: None of the text in your browser, including the interface elements, are anti-aliased.  Have you tried this on a different computer to see if the issue persists?  I doubt it will.

Comment: I didnt tryed, so you think you this is because of my computer?

Comment: Yes, it looks like an issue with your computer.

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on typography and rendering used by the browser, you can try to set this to improve the text:

```
html * {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```